# Unable to open ReactJS website on localhost. downloaded from Github

Tags: reactjs, github, web-development-server

I had downloaded many websites from GitHub and other free sources.
But they don't have any node modules. so, unable to open the website at localhost:3000

Comment: github folders does'nt have a node modules to reduce size you can run ```npm install``` command to get node modules

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install npm using `npm install` after this node modules folder is generated and then you can run project using `npm start` command